# sql query to find id name dependent on another id

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
| ID | NAME     | f_id | 
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | Mark     |  2   |
|  2 | Khilan   |  1   | 
|  3 | kaushik  |  7   | 
|  4 | Chaitali |  1   | 
|  5 | Hardik   |  3   | 
|  6 | Komal    |  4   |
|  7 | Muffy    | 7    |  
+----+----------+------+
```

I have to write a query to find favorites person from the list of people,
but the thing is a person can be its own favorite like in the table muffy has favorite person as muffy only. The results would look like this:

```
| ID | NAME     | fav      | 
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Mark     | Khilan   |
|  2 | Khilan   | Mark     | 
|  3 | kaushik  | Muffy    | 
|  4 | Chaitali | Mark     | 
|  5 | Hardik   | kaushik  | 
|  6 | Komal    | Chaitali |
|  7 | Muffy    | Muffy    |  
+----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inner join for this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, tmp.name AS favorite
FROM myTable m
JOIN myTable tmp ON tmp.id = m.fav_id;
```

This will align the two table with itself on the condition that the id of one table matches the favorite id of the other, and you can adjust your select clause to get the favorite's name instead of their id.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2763/2) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join to get this as:

```
Select a.id, a.name, b.name as fav  from table a inner join table b on a.f_id = b.id
```